# Pass Model to javascript change event from Kendo DropdownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

What is the best way to pass my entire Model from the dropdown list to the JavaScript change event. I've spent hours on this with no luck

```
@model InputApp.DropdownModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .Name(Model.Name)
        .Text(Model.PlaceHolder)
        .BindTo(Model.ListItems)
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .Enable(Model.Enabled)
        .Events(e =>
        {
            e.Change("dropdown_change");
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new {@id= Model.ID.ToString() })
)



function dropdown_change() {

}
```

Any help or just pointing me to good resources will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pass the whole model to the JavaScript handler, because when you use ASP.Net helper to create dropdown list the model actally is not binded. The equivalent of the helper output would be just JavaScript code to generate html with data items. You can however get data item info, you will need `select` event instead of `change`:

```
.Events(e =>
{
   e.Select("onSelect");
})
```

And in JavaScript

```
function onSelect(e) {
   var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
   console.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.Text + " : " + dataItem.Value + ")" );
}
```

See [telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/events) for details

Another option would be pass the whole model to the client-side and bind it using kendo JavaScript, see [sample](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events)

Comment: Thanks for that! that has shed some light! Much appreciated! So there is no way to pass the full model, but rather best to retrieve data from the input attributes as you have demonstrated, cheers!